# In C++, what data type does the operator sizeof returns?

Tags: c++

When I compile this line in Qt:

```
printf("size: %d\n", sizeof(fValue));
```

I get this warning:

> "Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long
>   long' "

so I deduce that the data type is 'unsigned long long', but I cannot find that information written anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[`sizeof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns a [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), which is an *implementation-defined* unsigned integer.  In your case, your compiler is using `unsigned long long`.

Comment: ... and the `printf` format specifier for a `size_t` is `%z`, in case you were wondering OP.

Comment: @PaulSanders It's `%zu`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat gak, my bad

Comment: Though, it would be better to use `std::cout` instead of `printf()`, then you don't have to worry about print specifiers: `std::cout << "size: " << sizeof(fValue) << "\n";`

Answer (score 2):

*but I cannot find that information written anywhere.*

Just so you know, it's here: [[expr.sizeof]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#5):

> The result of `sizeof` and `sizeof...` is a prvalue of type `std​::​size_­t`.